# EP1 instance costs in function App Premium Elastic Plan w.r.t. Scale-up and Scale-out settings

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

Can anyone please elaborate me the minimum and miximum price of below settings(for reference) while creating the FunctionApp in Premium Elastic plan(EP1).

**Q.** How does **Plan Scale out
Minimum Instances**,
**Maximum Burst** and 
**App Scale out
Pre-Warmed Instances** settings of FunctionApp affects costs?

[image]

Comment: Hi Bikram, may I know if the answer explain your confusion ?

Comment: Hi Hury, upto some extent!
But my question is- with respect to above screenshot. if per instance charge is X per month, does keeping minimum instances to 10 would charge me 10X per month plus charges of maximum burst with respect to its utilization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan)

"You are charged for each instance allocated in the minimum instance count regardless if functions are executing or not."

[image]

Comment: Does this mean, if the function scales out to 10 based on maximum burst, the cost is 10x?

Comment: I too am curious, why is no one answering this? Does 10 minimum mean you're paying 10x the price?

Comment: Yes, 10x price, if 10x minium

Answer (score 2):

For your question, I summarized the pricing rules below for your reference:

Azure Functions Premium plan provides the same features and scaling mechanism used on the Consumption plan, but the difference is we can set the Pre-Warmed instances.

Premium plan can avoid cold start by setting the Pre-Warmed instances, for example we can set 1 instance for Pre-Warmed(but smaller than minimum instances size which you set), then if the function app hasn't been requested for a long time, we just need to pay for the warm instance. The price is shown as below:

[image]
The EP1 plan is 3.5GB for each instance, so we can calculate the price.

While the function app is requested, then it will billed on a per second basis based on the number of vCPU-s and GB-s(based on the number of the instance which your function app uses on a per secnond).

Hope it would be helpful to your question~